# How to ignore Json parse error?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Query returns a list, but sometimes objects in that list can't be parsed. In this case I want to return null and return list with null objects. How to do this? Now I try to create custom adapter

```
public class ServiceMenuItemAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
@Override
public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
    if (type.getRawType() != ServiceMenuItem.class) return null;

    TypeAdapter<ServiceMenuItem> defaultAdapter = (TypeAdapter<ServiceMenuItem>) gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
    return (TypeAdapter<T>) new ServiceMenuItemAdapter(defaultAdapter);
}

private class ServiceMenuItemAdapter extends TypeAdapter<ServiceMenuItem> {

    protected TypeAdapter<ServiceMenuItem> defaultAdapter;


    public ServiceMenuItemAdapter(TypeAdapter<ServiceMenuItem> defaultAdapter) {
        this.defaultAdapter = defaultAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, ServiceMenuItem value) throws IOException {
        defaultAdapter.write(out, value);
    }

    @Override
    public ServiceMenuItem read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
       try{
           return defaultAdapter.read(in);
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           return null
       }
    }
```

Comment: first check if JSON object has that object then parse it. like this if(jsonObject.has("object")) String str=jsonObject.getString("object")

Comment: Are you getting null or an exception? if null, check "not null" if exception surround with try/catch

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `NullPointerException` you better make use of `optString()` instead of `getString()`

If you are fetching the data from JSON at any time, you might have null data for a particular Key value, at that time instead of implementing Null conditions, better make use of this optimized method  `optString("<keyname>")`